# How to deeply compare nested types in Python

Tags: python

In python, it's easy to test whether two variables have the same top-level type:

```
In [1]: s1 = 'bob'
In [2]: s2 = 'tom'
In [3]: type(s1) == type(s2)
Out[3]: True
```

But in the case where types are nested, it's not so easy:

```
In [4]: strlist = ['bob', 'tom']
In [5]: intlist = [5, 6, 7]
In [6]: type(strlist) == type(intlist)
Out[6]: True
```

Is there a **general** way to "deeply" compare two variables such that:

```
deepcompare(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]) == False
deepcompare([42, 43], [1, 2]) == True
```

?

EDIT:

To define the question a bit more, let's say this includes both list length and heterogeneous list types:

```
deepcompare([1, 2, 3], [1, 2]) == False
deepcompare([1, 3], [2, 'b']) == False
deepcompare([1, 'a'], [2, 'b']) == True
```

Comment: Do you care about equal sizes as well? Or is it just making sure that regardless of how many are in there, they just have to have the same types inside the structure?

Comment: For there to be a *general* way implies that this is a well-defined problem, but it isn't. Is the length of a list relevant to its "type"? What do you do with non-homogenous container types?

Comment: Are we talking only one level of nesting?

Comment: You could recursively create two structures just containing *the types of the objects at each position*, then compare them directly - `[str, str] != [int, int]`, for example. Can you assume that the structures contain homogeneous types, or might you end up looking at e.g. `deepcompare(['a', 1], ['b', 2])` (and what should the result be)?

Comment: @tzaman point well taken, see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you could create what I've called a *"type map"* recursively:

```
def typemap(lst_or_obj):
    if not isinstance(lst_or_obj, list):
        return type(lst_or_obj)
    return [typemap(obj) for obj in lst_or_obj]
```

Then use this to get the types *within* your structures:

```
a = [1, 2, ['three', 4]]
b = [5, 6, ['seven', 8]]
c = [9, 10, [11, 'twelve']]

ta = typemap(a)
tb = typemap(b)
tc = typemap(c)

print(ta)
print(tb)
print(tc)

print(ta == tb)
print(ta == tc)
```

Output:

```
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, [<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>]]
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, [<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>]] 
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, [<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>]]
True
False
```

Then your function is simply:

```
def deepcompare(a, b):
    return typemap(a) == typemap(b)
```

If you need to deal with things other than lists, you can trivially expand the `isinstance` check to `(list, tuple)`, but you can quickly run into issues with things like `str` (recursively iterating over strings is a problem because a single character or empty string is an iterable of itself, so your program explodes) and `dict` (ordering issues, comparing keys and/or values, ...).

Comment: Nice! Although for this to be a bit more general, should the first line in `typemap` check whether the `list_or_obj` is iterable, instead of whether it is a list?

Comment: @spiffman is that a requirement? The issue with iterability is that e.g. strings and dictionaries are iterable, but you likely want to handle those differently to lists and tuples.

Comment: Not necessarily, I was more just wondering whether that would provide a more general solution, but you're right, the strings case is especially problematic there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is the way to go and clear. You can also use `collections.Iterable`  for type checking in order to make it more comprehensive.

Comment: @Kasramvd please read [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042488/how-to-deeply-compare-nested-types-in-python/36042816?noredirect=1#comment59734678_36042816), where I point out why simply checking for iterables isn't a silver bullet

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I missed that, but you can add multiple type to `isinstance` or at least mention it in question. Anyway well done.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I do this is by using this function:

```
def getDeepTypes(items):
    types = [type(x) for x in items]
    return (types[0] if all(x == types[0] for x in types) else None)
```

This uses various list comprehensions to get the deep type of a list. If they aren't all the same, `None` is returned.

```
>>> getDeepTypes([1, 2, 3])
int
>>> getDeepTypes(["foo", "bar"])
str
>>> print(getDeepTypes([1, "foo"]))
None
```

So you could do:

```
getDeepTypes(['a', 'b']) == getDeepTypes([1, 2]) # False
getDeepTypes([42, 43]) == getDeepTypes([1, 2]) # True
```

Comment: I would use `any` here instead. It would short circuit the moment it breaks your condition. Also, this only handles a single level

Comment: Would `getDeepTypes(items)` be more efficient if you created a set of all types and just checked if the length of the set is 1?
`types = {type(x) for x in items}` and `if len(types) == 1 return types.pop()`.